# WebP images doesn't display in safari although added polyfill

Tags: javascript, jpeg, polyfills, webp

Google insight told me to convert my JPG images to WebP. It reduced wieght of every image by a half but the issue is that Safari (probably worst browser even edge better please don't use it so it will die) on Mac doesn't display webP.

I've added [this script](http://webpjs.appspot.com/) to my app which I believe is polyfill but it didn't help. Also it's written there to download both files but `webpjs-0.0.2.swf`
 is broken link. Is there some working polyfill?

Most of images are served as background images often as binded inline styles. So for example [this polyfill](https://github.com/chase-moskal/webp-hero/issues/7) won't work because css support is plan for a future.

In turn [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-webp-plugin) have lack of documentation around css/inline-style and also need some work to be done to replace path in every image in every component.

If you have mac and safari - [live demo](http://activeyachtclub.com)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I [custom built modernizr](https://modernizr.com/download?apng-arrow-atobbtoa-bdi-beacon-bloburls-blobworkers-capture-classlist-contains-cssresize-cssscrollbar-csstransforms-csstransforms3d-csstransformslevel2-csstransitions-cssvalid-cssvhunit-cssvmaxunit-cssvminunit-cssvwunit-datachannel-datalistelem-dataset-datauri-dataworkers-details-devicemotion_deviceorientation-directory-documentfragment-es5-es5array-es5date-es5function-es5object-es5string-es5syntax-es5undefined-es6array-es6collections-es6math-es6number-es6object-es6string-eventsource-fetch-fileinput-filereader-filesystem-formattribute-formvalidation-framed-generators-getusermedia-hidden-hovermq-imgcrossorigin-inlinesvg-inputformaction-inputformenctype-inputformmethod-inputformtarget-jpeg2000-jpegxr-localizednumber-localstorage-lowbandwidth-matchmedia-microdata-mutationobserver-oninput-outputelem-passiveeventlisteners-peerconnection-picture-placeholder-pointermq-preserve3d-progressbar_meter-promises-requestautocomplete-rgba-ruby-sandbox-scriptasync-scriptdefer-scrollsnappoints-seamless-sessionstorage-shapes-sharedworkers-siblinggeneral-sizes-smil-speechrecognition-speechsynthesis-srcdoc-srcset-strictmode-stylescoped-subpixelfont-supports-svgasimg-svgclippaths-svgfilters-svgforeignobject-target-template-textalignlast-textareamaxlength-textshadow-texttrackapi_track-time-transferables-unknownelements-urlparser-urlsearchparams-userselect-variablefonts-videoautoplay-videocrossorigin-videoloop-videopreload-webglextensions-webp-webpalpha-webpanimation-websocketsbinary-websqldatabase-webworkers-willchange-wrapflow-xhr2-xhrresponsetype-xhrresponsetypearraybuffer-xhrresponsetypeblob-xhrresponsetypedocument-xhrresponsetypejson-xhrresponsetypetext-addtest-atrule-domprefixes-hasevent-mq-prefixed-prefixedcss-prefixedcssvalue-prefixes-setclasses-shiv-testallprops-testprop-teststyles) just took WebP checker from it and then used this approches:

for HTML image:

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="img/awesomeWebPImage.webp" type="image/webp">
  <source srcset="img/creakyOldJPEG.jpg" type="image/jpeg"> 
  <img src="img/creakyOldJPEG.jpg" alt="Alt Text!">
</picture>
```

for CSS image:

```
.no-webp .elementWithBackgroundImage {
  background-image: url("image.jpg");
}

.webp .elementWithBackgroundImage{
  background-image: url("image.webp");
}
```

for passing image link as props (within Vue2 application or any other front-end framework):

```
document.querySelector("html").classList[0] === 'webp' ? this.webpEnabled = true : this.webpEnabled = false;
this.webpEnabled ? this.currentImages = this.imagesWebp : this.currentImages = this.imagesJpeg

<some-component :image="currentImages[0]"></some-component>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for a simple (no JS) solution to the problem of .webp images failing to display as CSS background images on Safari, you can just reach for the CSS background property:

```
background: url(image-filename.webp) center/contain no-repeat,
            url(image-filename.jpg) center/contain no-repeat;
```

The order of the images is strange, as it feels like you should put the older format *after* the .webp file.

Anyway, this provides a fallback image for Safari and other lesser browsers to use.

**EDIT**

The answer above works, but it's not a good solution as browsers just end up downloading both the images.

The "real" answer to using .webp cross-browser seems to require Modernizr and browser detection with JS - see here:

https://css-tricks.com/using-webp-images/#article-header-id-4

Comment: doesn't that cause *both* images to be loaded?!

Comment: @artfulrobot Actually... yes. The full answer is, therefore, annoyingly complex: https://css-tricks.com/using-webp-images/#article-header-id-4. I will update this answer.

Comment: Here working solution example
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64048033/1266559